# Problems about Sobolev Space

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega:=B(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}.$

(i) Consider the function $u(x):=1 /\|x\|^{a}, x \neq 0,$ where $a>0$

Let $a+1<N$ and $1 \leq p<\infty$ and show that $u \in W^{1, p}(\Omega)$ if and only if $(a+1) p<N$ (in particular, $u \notin W^{1, p}(\Omega)$ for all $p \geq N)$.

(ii)Let $\left\{x_{n}: n \in \mathbb{N}\right\} \subset \Omega$ be a countable dense set and define
$$u(x):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n}} \frac{1}{\left\|x-x_{n}\right\|^{a}}, \quad x \in \Omega \backslash \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\{x_{n}\right\}.$$

where $0<a<N-1.$ Prove that $u \in W^{1, p}(\Omega)$ if and only if $(a+1) p<N,$ but $u$ is unbounded in each open subset of $\Omega$.

For (i),I have proved $\|\nabla u\|=C/\|x\|^{a+1},$but I don't know what to do next.

For (ii),I have no idea about it...

Can someone give me a  detailed hint?Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest you work on (i) first, and check the $W^{1,p}$ norm of $u$.

Comment: And (ii) follows from (i) by observing that the function defined in (ii) (I would call it $v$) is a sum of dilation and translation of $u$ in (i). How is the $\|v\|_{1,p}$ related to $\|u\|_{1,p}$ (more precisely, when will $\|v\|_{1,p}$ be finite)? The unboundedness is trivial.

Comment: @mathdoge Thanks for your answer first.I am confused about how we define $D^\alpha u$ at point $0$.Maybe it doesn't matter because of the integral's properties?

Comment: You're right, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Are you able to solve it by yourself? If you get stuck we could discuss.

Comment: @mathdoge I solved this problem,thank you!!!